# If $λ_1, λ_2,$ eigenvalues of $A$ and $λ_1=λ_2$, then $det(A) = λ_1^2$ or $det(A)=λ_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Ι know that $det(A) = λ_1 λ_2...λ_n$ but what happens when we have non-distinct eigenvalues? Do we multiply them with themselves or not? I would suppose that we do, but im not really sure and i cant really explain why. Can you shed some clarity?

Comment: yes exactely...

Comment: Just **try it** on a simple example, like a constant times the identity matrix!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my reasoning as to why it is the first option. As we know, the eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial  $p_{A}(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I)$. Since A is a 2x2 matrix, then this polynomial is degree 2, and so has 2 roots $\lambda _{1}$ and $\lambda _{2}$ (which are the eigenvalues of $A$). The determinant of $A$ is the product of these roots $\lambda _{1} \lambda _{2}$. In the possible case that $\lambda _{1} = \lambda _{2}$, then the determinant can also be expressed as $\lambda _{1}^2$ or $\lambda _{2}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If a square matrix $A$ of size $n$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$, since it is triangularisable (at least in $\mathbb C$), there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PTP^{-1}$, where
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&*&\cdots&*\\0&\lambda_2&\ddots&\vdots\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&*\\0&\cdots&0&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So $\det A=\det(PTP^{-1})=\det T=\lambda_1\times\cdots\times\lambda_n$.